# Does every group have a 'cyclization'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Here's the question:

> Does every group have a 'cyclization'? That is, let $G$ be a group. Does there necessarily exist a cyclic group $C$ and a surjective homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow C$ such that for every other cyclic group $H$ such that there is a surjective homomorphism $\psi:G\rightarrow H$ then there is a unique homomorphism $\phi:C\rightarrow H$ such that $\psi=\phi\circ \varphi$?

This question is inspired by the existence of the abelianization of a group. Here's what I have done:

Let $G$ be a group and $C$ a cyclic group such that $\varphi:G\rightarrow C$ is a surjective homomorphism. Since $C$ is cyclic, $C=\langle c\rangle$ for some $c\in C$. Let $c^m$ and $c^n$ be two other elements of $C$. Since $\varphi$ is surjective, there are elements $g$ and $h\in G$ such that $\varphi(g)=c^m$ and $\varphi(h)=c^n$ (assume $m$ and $n$ are non-zero). Thus

$$\varphi(h)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)/n}=c^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}=\varphi(g)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)/m}$$

This implies that 
$$\varphi\left(g^{\text{lcm}(m,n)/m}h^{-\text{lcm}(m,n)/n}\right)=1_C$$

We can conclude then that 
$$N=\langle\;g^{\text{lcm}(m,n)/m}h^{-\text{lcm}(m,n)/n}\;|\;g,h\in G\text{ and }\;m,n\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}\rangle\subseteq\ker\varphi$$

In addition, since
$$xg^{\text{lcm}(m,n)/m}h^{-\text{lcm}(m,n)/n} x^{-1}=(xgx^{-1})^{\text{lcm}(m,n)/m}(xhx^{-1})^{-\text{lcm}(m,n)/n}$$
for any $x\in G$, we get that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Further, we see that $[G,G]\subseteq N$ since 
$$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=(xy)^{\text{lcm}(-1,1)/1}(x^{-1}y^{-1})^{-\text{lcm}(-1,1)/-1}\in N$$

So, I seem to be on the right track. Perhaps $G/N$ is itself cyclic. However, even though I know that $G/N$ is abelian, I have no idea on how to show it is cyclic (if it necessarily is).

---

Stepping back from the problem, it would suffice to show that every abelian group has a cyclization since every map onto a cyclic quotient would have to factor through the abelianization of a group. This seems to be obvious. If $G$ is an abelian group which is finitely generated then the Structure Theorem for Finitely-generated Abelian Groups tells us that $G$ is isomorphic to a group that looks like $$C_{d_1}\times C_{d_2}\times\cdots\times C_{d_n}\times FA_m$$

where $d_1\mid d_2\mid \cdots\mid d_n$, each $C_{d_i}$ represents a cyclic group of order $d_i$, and $FA_m$ represents a free abelian group on $m$ generators.

In the absence of a $FA_m$ term, the cyclization would be $C_{d_n}$. In the presence of a $FA_m$ term, the cyclization would be $FA_1$.

For an abelian group that is not finitely generated, I believe the cyclization would be the trivial group. But I'm having difficulty with this claim. Maybe there's a counter-example here.

Comment: IMHO: Who doesn't think of $Z_p\times Z_p$ immediately should look at some examples of small finite groups first before studying more theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cyclizations need not exist in general. Consider the group $G=\oplus_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Z / p_i \mathbb Z$, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime. $G$ surjects onto $\mathbb Z / q \mathbb Z$ for any prime $q$, so $\mathbb Z/ n \mathbb Z$ cannot be a cyclization for any $n$. On the other hand, all elements are of finite order, so it's clear that $\mathbb Z$ is not a cyclization.

**Edit.** After some more thought, I've realized that we can generalize the above: *cyclizations cannot exist for any direct sum of cyclic groups that is not itself cyclic*. Roughly, the universal property that you've specified forces the cyclizaton map to be injective, which forces the original group to be cyclic. More precisely, suppose

$$G \simeq \oplus_{i\in \mathbb N} G_i$$ where each $G_i$ is cyclic. If $\varphi: G \rightarrow C$ is a cyclization, then for each $i$ we must have $f_i: C \rightarrow G_i$ so that

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
G @>\varphi>> C \\
@VV\pi_i V @V f_i VV \\
{G_i} @>1>> G_i
\end{CD}$$ commutes, where $\pi_i$ is the $i$-th projection.

For any $n$-tuple $x \in G$ with a non-identity component, we can choose $\pi_i$ so that $\pi_i(x) \neq e$. Since $\pi_i=f_i\circ \varphi$, this forces $\varphi(x) \neq e$. Therefore $\varphi$ must be an injection, which implies $G \simeq \varphi(G) \subset C$. Since [subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Cyclic_Group_is_Cyclic), this is impossible unless $G$ itself is cyclic.

Comment: My background with $\Bbb Z_p$ is very limited. And I think your proof of the non-existence of a surjection onto $\Bbb Z$ is cleaner. Thanks for the counter-example!

Comment: @Bryan I'm glad my initial answer was helpful! After some more contemplation, I realize that cyclizations are much harder to come by than I originally thought. In particular, my last statement regarding $\oplus_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ having a nontrivial cyclization was false (it does not have one at all). Please see the edit to my post.

Comment: Your argument is actually similar to mine and works for finitely generated groups.

Comment: @QuangHoang indeed it is -- I hadn't read yours carefully beforehand, but now I see that we're getting at the same fundamental issue. As for generalizing to finitely generated groups -- you are referring to the fact that the abelianization of a finitely generated group will be a finitely generated abelian group, so we can apply the structure theorem?

Comment: Yes, cyclization of $G$, if exists, is also the cyclization of the abelianization of $G$. So in fact, one can characterize which $G$ has a cyclization. However, I'm not sure that it will be something useful, hence the lack of the concept in literature.

Comment: @QuangHoang not every abelian group is a direct sum of cyclic groups -- so perhaps we haven't completely characterized which groups have cyclizations just yet? I would agree that, because "cyclization $\iff$ cyclic" for so many familiar groups (e.g. finite, finitely generated), the concept would probably not be of great use. But, from a pedagogical standpoint, it seems valuable to think through the concept and work out the various cases.

Comment: Indeed, I was talking about f.g groups only.

Answer (score 8):

Let $G = \mathbf Z_p$ be the additive group of $p$-adic integers. It has arbitrarily large finite cyclic quotients (that's part of what being an inverse limit of arbitrarily large finite cyclic groups is all about), so if $G$ has a cyclization $C$ then $C$ can't be finite, and thus $C \cong \mathbf Z$. Thus there would have to be a surjective group homomorphism $\mathbf Z_p \rightarrow \mathbf Z$. We want to show that is impossible. [Edit: See Alex's comment for a simpler approach than what I write below.]

Homomorphisms of abelian groups are the same thing as $\mathbf Z$-module homomorphisms, and free modules are projective modules, so if there were a surjective group homomorphism $\mathbf Z_p \rightarrow \mathbf Z$ then there would be an isomorphism of abelian groups $\mathbf Z_p \cong \mathbf Z \oplus H$ for some abelian group $H$. Then, since $\mathbf Z$ has every finite cyclic group as a quotient, we can realize every finite cyclic group as a quotient of $\mathbf Z_p$, but the only finite quotient groups of $\mathbf Z_p$ are of $p$-power order, so we have a contradiction.

Here is why all finite quotient groups of $\mathbf Z_p$ have $p$-power order. Suppose there is a surjective group homomorphism $\mathbf Z_p \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is a nontrivial finite group, necessarily abelian. Let $q$ be a prime other than $p$. From the decomposition of $A$ as a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, there's a surjective homomorphism $A \rightarrow A_q$, where $A_q$ is the $q$-Sylow subgroup of $A$. Therefore we'd have a surjective group homomorphism $f \colon \mathbf Z_p \rightarrow A_q$. Set $|A_q| = q^m$. Then $q^m\mathbf Z_p \subset \ker f$, but $q^m\mathbf Z_p = \mathbf Z_p$ since $q$ and $p$ are distinct primes, so $\mathbf Z_p \subset \ker f$. Thus $q^m = 1$, so the $q$-Sylow subgroup of $A$ is trivial for every prime $q$ other than $p$, and therefore $A$ is a group of $p$-power order.

Comment: @Bryan That's not right, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is torsion free. That said, every element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $q$-divisible for any prime $q\ne p$, and so its image in $\mathbb{Z}$ must be zero. Or, in other words, $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})=0$.

Comment: @KCd He almost certainly thought you meant $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. That said, the argument I said above works.

Comment: My apologies. I was reading "$\oplus_{k\in\Bbb N} \Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z$" when I saw $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: @KCd Concerning your edit, why is what I wrote not sufficient? Every element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $q$-divisibile for a prime $q\ne p$-- namely for any $x$, we have that $x=qy$ for $y=q^{-1}x$. Thus, if $f:\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a group map, then for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ we'd have $f(x)=f(qy)=qf(y)$ for all primes $q$ except $p$. But then this implies that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Yes, your argument is simpler.  I was trying to work out an argument myself before I read your comment as closely as I should have.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: I was trying to give an argument eliminating each prime other than $p$ separately, while you use them all together (you appeal to there being infinitely many primes). Your argument also can be made to work prime-by-prime by looking at $q^m$-divisibility for fixed $q \not= p$ and arbitrarily large $m$.

Comment: @KCd Ah, I see. That's a fair point. It is nice to note that hidden in your argument, and as in mine, there are no non-zero maps to $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Regardless, nice answer. +1

Comment: @AlexYoucis: swap the direction of the maps. :)

Comment: @KCd Oops, stupid initial object in $\mathbf{Ring}$. :)

Comment: Bryan, actually the direct sum $\bigoplus_{k \geq 1} \mathbf Z/p^k\mathbf Z$ is also an example. It has no nonzero homomorphism to $\mathbf Z$ since its elements are all of finite order, and it has no finite cyclization since it has arbitrarily large finite quotients.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is negative. For a counterexample, one can consider $G=C_p\times C_p$. Then the only cyclic image of $G$ is $C_p$. If there would be a "cyclization" $C$ of $G$, then it would be isomorphic to $C_p$. Moreover, there is an exact sequence
$$1\to U\to G\stackrel{\varphi}\to C\to 1,$$
where $U$ is some copy of $C_p$ in $G$. But one then can construct a surjection $G\to U$ which obviously does not factor through $\varphi$.

Comment: Can you construct this surjection? Any map from $C_p\times C_p$ to $C_p$ is either trivial or equivalent to a projection. How do those not factor through a projection onto $C_p$?

Comment: I don't see how this is a counterexample. Why does the surjection $G\to U$ not factor through $\varphi$? Isn't $U$ going to be isomorphic to $C$?

Comment: If $G\stackrel{\psi}{\to} U$ factors through $\varphi$, that is, $\psi=\phi\circ\varphi$, then $\ker\varphi\subset\ker\psi$. Now where's the contradiction that we are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\mathbb{Q}$. If $C$ is cyclic, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$, then $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}, C)=0$, and no surjective homorphism is possible.

Comment: The trivial group is cyclic. You've actually showed that the rationals have a trivial 'cyclization'.

Comment: @Bryan - I assumed you wanted a non-trivial cyclization.

Comment: No. Trivial groups are perfectly fine.

Comment: Doesn't every group have a trivial cyclicization?

Comment: It might make a better question to ask what groups have nontrivial cyclizations, since not all have non-trivial ones.

Comment: @Alexander - It certainly seems every group has a trivial one, which is why I don't think the trivial case is very interesting. I'm kind of distracted by other obligations at the moment, but it seems that $\mathbb{Z}$ has both itself and the trivial group as cyclizations.

Comment: A cyclization is not just a group. It's a group and a homomorphism with a specific universal property embodied in the highlighted text. Like the abelianization of a group. If I had asked the community to go through the abelianization of a group, no one would ask "Doesn't every group have a trivial abelianization?" or say "It might make a better question to ask what groups have nontrivial abelianizations".

Comment: @Bryan Right, but what I'm saying is, doesn't the trivial homomorphism to the group of order $1$ satisfy the conditions you gave?  Am I misunderstanding them?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: A nontrivial map cannot factor through the trivial group

Comment: Ahh, I see, I had the maps backwards.  Good question!